# upload a video to my ASP.net web site

Tags: asp.net

I'm use this code section to upload a video for a my ASP.net web site.but it gives error like this " mySrc inaccessible due to it's protection level" How can i fix it

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
           playSound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error in Page:" + ex.Message);
        }
}


public void playSound()
{
    mySrc = @"http://google.com//alarm.wav";
}
```

### aspx page

```
<asp:panel id="Panel1" runat="server" height="1px" width="1px" xmlns:asp="#unknown">
            <object classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" id="player">
                class="style3" height="1px" width="1px" >
                <param name="url" value="<%=mySrc %>" />
                <param name="src" value="<%=mySrc %>" />
                <param name="showcontrols" value="true" />
                <param name="autostart" value="true" />
               <!--[if !IE]>-->
                    <object type="video/x-ms-wmv" data="<%=mySrc %>" class="style4" height="1px" width="1px">
                        <param name="src" value="<%=mySrc %>" />
                        <param name="autostart" value="true" />
                        <param name="controller" value="true" />
                </object>
               <!--<![endif]-->
           </object>
        </asp:panel>
```

Comment: where you declared `mySrc` ?

Answer (score 0):

do like this

`public mySrc =string.Empty;` // use public and global variable. so that you can access.

```
public void playSound()
{
    mySrc = @"http://google.com//alarm.wav";
}
```